# Migrate SVN repository to GIT - Keep Line endings / Whitespaces / Encoding

Tags: git, svn

I've tried to migrate a svn repository to git, but git changed my line endings and white spaces.

The svn repository contains files with different encodings and line endings. The rules for whitespaces also vary from file to file. In most cases this is by design, not by accident.

I am using tortoisegit 1.8.15.0 and git 2.5.0.windows.1 for the migration.

How can I ensure that, git keeps everything as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask `git` to ignore whitespaces using `git config`.

For end of lines:
`git config core.autocrlf false`

For whitespaces:
`git config core.whitespace -blank-at-eol,-blank-at-eof,-space-before-tab,-trailing-space,-indent-with-non-tab,-tab-in-indent`

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Use `--global` if you want your changes to apply for all your projects.